# Image not loading when $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] is inside echo vs inside src attribute

Tags: php, html

Why does this work:

```
<img src='<?php $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];?>/images/image.png' width=50 height=50>
```

But this does not:

```
$documentroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
echo("<img src='$documentroot/images/image.png' width=50 height=50>");
```

Both file paths are correct. The issue is that the first one loads the image but the second one loads the thumbnail error when an image fails to load.

Comment: Because for one thing, you never echo'd the first one and doesn't do anything, where the 2nd one works because you're most likely on a hosted service that only lets you go to the public root instead of the server's system root. Would you like this to be an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0):

You've got two different (but related) entities here:

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` gives you the server's native operating system path where the files are stored, like `/var/www/mysite/public`. The public should never see this.

The `src` attribute contains the address for the image. This can be a full address starting with `http://`, an absolute path starting with `/`, or a relative path.

In the case it starts with a slash, it is interpreted to be anchored at the document root directory. I.e., `src="/images/foo.png"` means that your file is actually stored in `/var/www/mysite/public/images/foo.png`. You don't need to ever add the `/var/www/mysite/public` part -- the web server does that for you.